# fusioncharts stacked graph set SeriesName in array

Tags: php, sql, fusioncharts, stacked-chart

I am trying to build a stacked chart in fusioncharts.
In this graph i want to show the sold products for each brand in a category.

I'm trying to build the xml layout like the [following](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/stacked-charts/creating-stacked-charts.html)

Do not mind the sql, i get the right results.

But only the weeks display correctly, i was thinking maybe array brands is going wrong.

```
function graphnew($caption,$width,$height,$id,$pdo,$select,$zoeken){
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `datum` FROM `weeks` GROUP BY `datum` "); 
$result0 = $stm->execute();
$results0 = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$stm3 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM `weeks` WHERE `".$select."`      = '".$zoeken."'"); 
$result = $stm3->execute();
$results = $stm3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stm4 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(`sales`) AS 'sales' FROM   `weeks` WHERE `".$select."` = '".$zoeken."' GROUP by `brand`,`datum`  "); 
   $result1 = $stm4->execute();
$results1 = $stm4->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$arrData = array(
            "chart" => array(
              "caption" => "$caption",
              "xAxisName"=> "Dagen",
                "yAxisName"=> "aantal",
              "numberPrefix"=>"",
              "showValues" => "0",

              "lineThickness"=> "2",


              "displayValue" => "aantal",
              "theme" => "zune",
              "xAxisLineThickness"=> "3"


            )
        );

         $datum=array();
        $brands=array();
        $sales=array();



// Push the data into the array

        foreach($results0 as $row) {

        array_push($datum, array(
                "label" => $row["datum"]
                )
            );

        }
        foreach($results1 as $row) {
            array_push($sales, array(
                "value" => $row["sales"]
                )
            );
        }

        foreach($results as $row) {
            array_push($brands, array(
                "seriesName" => $row["brand"],

                )
            );
        }



             $arrData["categories"]= array(array("category"=> $datum));  
             $arrData["dataset"] = array(array("seriesName"=> $brands, "data"=>$sales));


  // Translate to json
  $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

    /**
     *  Creates a `columnChart` chart object using the FusionCharts PHP class constructor.
     *  Syntax for the constructor: `FusionCharts("type of * chart", "unique chart id", "width of chart",
     *  "height of chart", "div id to render the chart", "data format", "data source")`
     */
    $columnChart = new FusionCharts("stackedcolumn2d", "myFirstChart3" , $width, $height, $id, "json", $jsonEncodedData);
    // Render the chart
    $columnChart->render();



   }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D8ro.jpg)